# Ruby bang strange behaviour

Tags: ruby

I wrote  the following code:

```
print "Please enter a string"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
if user_input.include? "s"
  print "Changing #{user_input} to #{user_input.gsub!(/s/,'th')}"
else
  print "No s in the string"
end
```

and I found that `user_input` and `user_input.gsub!(/s/,'th')` contain the same value. This happens because of the bang operation on `gsub` and because they are part of the same string.

Splitting the print in two lines changes the behavior:

```
print "Changing #{user_input} to "
print "#{user_input.gsub!(/s/,'th')}"
```

I wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: Pro Tip: if you think you found a bug in a compiler/interpreter/whatever, you didn't. The bug is in your code. :)

Comment: I know indeed I marked the question "basic" because I just started learnig ruby as my original question stated

Comment: This was a joke, btw. Not an insult or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug.

String interpolation (the `"#{}"` operator) works by finding all the dynamic parts, evaluating them and then glueing static and dynamic parts together into one string. Since all dynamic parts are evaluated prior to concatenation, `gsub!` mutates the object which `user_input` points to. So the first appearance of `inner_page` in that string will see the updated value.

Solution: don't use dangerous `gsub!`, use safe `gsub`.

You can observe here, how it *really* happens (VM instructions). This will probably be Chinese to you at the moment, but in a few years you'll understand. :)

```
code = <<-RUBY
  user_input = 'blah'
  print "Changing \#{user_input} to \#{user_input.gsub!(/s/,'th')}"
RUBY

puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.new(code).disasm
```

[image: disasm]

Comment: Anyway is different from java code
    int i=0;
    System.out.print(String.format("testing %d %d",i,++i));
and has the opposite behavior of 
    System.out.print(String.format("testing %d %d",i,i++));

Comment: @Antonio: these java examples are irrelevant. Try ones where you mutate a string in place, you'll see the same thing. (hint: primitive value vs object reference)

Comment: String test = "are you sure?";
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s",test,test.substring(0,7)));
But no bang operation :(